# FlutterError - Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, global-key

I'm encountering a "Duplicate GlobalKey detected in the widget tree" error when using a `PageView.builder` in Flutter along with the `Screenshot` widget from the `screenshot` package. The error occurs when I scroll to the next page in the `PageView`. I'm not sure how to properly manage the `GlobalKey` instances to prevent this error. Here's my code setup:

I have a `CurrentAffairsScreen` widget containing a `PageView.builder` that renders a list of `CurrentAffairsStory` widgets, and I want to capture screenshots of the entire screen using the `Screenshot` widget. The `BottomNavBar` widget is responsible for capturing and sharing screenshots.

#### code for `CurrentAffairsScreen()`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

import '../../home/classes/date.list.class.dart';
import '../../internet.check/wraper/internet.check.wraper.dart';

import '../classes/current.affairs.class.dart';
import '../widgets/bottom.nav.bar.dart';
import '../widgets/current.affairs.story.dart';

class CurrentAffairsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentAffairsScreen({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/current-affairs-screen';

  @override
  State<CurrentAffairsScreen> createState() => _CurrentAffairsScreenState();
}

class _CurrentAffairsScreenState extends State<CurrentAffairsScreen> {
  PageController controller = PageController();
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentAffairsList =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DateList;
   
    final List<CurrentAffairs> currentAffairs =
        currentAffairsList.currentAffairsList;

    return InternetCheckWraper(
      widget: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(currentAffairsList.date),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
                padEnds: true,
                controller: controller,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: currentAffairs.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, i) => CurrentAffairsStory(
                  imgUrl: currentAffairs[i].imgUrl,
                  header: currentAffairs[i].header,
                  body: currentAffairs[i].body,
                  source: currentAffairs[i].source,
                  screenshotController: screenshotController,
                ),
              ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(
              screenshotController: screenshotController,
            ),),
    );
  }
}
```

While running the above code there is no error in the the first page of `pageview.builder()`
but, when I scroll to next page, I have got the following error in `framework.dart`

#### Exception has occurred.

```
- FlutterError (Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [GlobalKey#9d1f3]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Screenshot(state: ScreenshotState#55d8f)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.)
```

### code for `CurrentAffairsStory()`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

class CurrentAffairsStory extends StatelessWidget {
  final String header;
  final String body;
  final String source;
  final String imgUrl;
  final ScreenshotController screenshotController;

  const CurrentAffairsStory({
    Key? key,
    required this.header,
    required this.body,
    required this.source,
    required this.imgUrl,
    required this.screenshotController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Screenshot(
      controller: screenshotController,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              if (imgUrl != "noImg" && imgUrl.isNotEmpty)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                  child: Image(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(imgUrl),
                  ),
                ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      header,
                      textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    MarkdownBody(
                      data: body,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          source,
                          textScaleFactor: 0.75,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### code for `BottomNavBar()`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../functions/get.saved.view.mode.dart';
import '../providers/viewmode.provider.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScreenshotController screenshotController;
  const BottomNavBar({
    super.key,
    required this.screenshotController,
  });

  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SizedBox(
      height: 45,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).popUntil(
                ModalRoute.withName("/"),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.screenshotController.capture().then(
                  (image) async {
                    if (image != null) {
                      Directory directory =
                          await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                      File imageFile =
                          await File('${directory.path}/.png').create();
                      await imageFile.writeAsBytes(image);
                      XFile imageXFile = XFile(imageFile.path);
                      await Share.shareXFiles(
                        [imageXFile],
                 
                      );
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Additionally, I'm trying to share the captured screenshots using the `Share` package, but I'm unsure if my approach in the `BottomNavBar` widget is correct.

Please explain with some **examples**.
*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: a workaround is to remove `Screenshot()` from `CurrentAffairsStory()` widget then wrap body of `CurrentAffairsScreen()` with `Screenshot()` and use the `screenshotController` here.

Answer (score 0):

You should give UniqueKey for every widget when you need to change widget position in the view. Flutter engine will know the position of the widget from the key you provided. Here is the example.  I do not test your code. I hope it will help.

```
class CurrentAffairsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentAffairsScreen({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/current-affairs-screen';

  @override
  State<CurrentAffairsScreen> createState() => _CurrentAffairsScreenState();
}

class _CurrentAffairsScreenState extends State<CurrentAffairsScreen> {
  PageController controller = PageController();
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentAffairsList =
    ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DateList;

    final List<CurrentAffairs> currentAffairs =
        currentAffairsList.currentAffairsList;

    return InternetCheckWraper(
      widget: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(currentAffairsList.date),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
          padEnds: true,
          controller: controller,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: currentAffairs.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => CurrentAffairsStory(
            key: UniqueKey(),// <= Here is the UniqueKey
            imgUrl: currentAffairs[i].imgUrl,
            header: currentAffairs[i].header,
            body: currentAffairs[i].body,
            source: currentAffairs[i].source,
            screenshotController: screenshotController,
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(
          screenshotController: screenshotController,
        ),),
    );
  }
```

Share package some issue in iOS iPad so you should give RenderBox to fix it.  Also i think you should give a file name and type before you create a file.
Here is the example implementation.

```
Builder(builder: (context) {
      return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
          child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (image != null) {
                  final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
                  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  File imageFile = await File('${directory.path}/yourFileName.png').create();

                  await imageFile.writeAsBytes(image);
                  XFile imageXFile = XFile(imageFile.path);
                  await Share.shareXFiles(
                    [imageXFile],
                    sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
                  );
                }
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.share, size: 2.5)));
    })
```

Comment: It did not work. Same error apperaered.
BTW, I am not developing for ios system, this is an android only project.

Comment: Try to add UniqueKey to the ScreenShot Widget. The error complain about ScreenShot. @DebabrataSamal